# Python: Numpy Array : cant access/reference to a numpy array from another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a data acquisation class that takes data and saves it into a numpy array.

```
voltage = float((data.decode())[0:-2]) * 1000
print(voltage)
self.xxList = np.append(self.xxList, [voltage])
```

Those lines are in a while loop which is managed by a thread. I return the "self.xxlist" with a simple getter:

```
def get_xlist(self):
    return self.xxList
```

Then i try to have a reference to the same list in another class, which of course has the instance of my data acquistion class.

```
 self.mySerial = SerialFirat(self)
 self.xaList = self.mySerial.get_xlist()
```

This doesn't work with numpy - The self.xaList always stays the same (empty) and doesnt update on any acquired data - but works with a regular python list which uses simple .append(data).

I guess this might be due the way an element is appended to a numpy array, which creates a new list and returns the reference to it, each time an element is appended. The list that i referenced is the first list and the newly created lists have some different adress so the referenced list always stays the same.

I couldnt find a work around to make it function like a normal python list. I would appriciate any help and a clarification if my conclusion on why it doesnt work is correct.

PS: I use the data to plot a live graph but the list - xaList - i feed to the plotting function is always empty and nothings is being plotted. If i directly feed the xxList (the List i write the serialData in) it works but that really leads to a crappy object oriented design

Comment: "Doesn't work"?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yes thanks i edited the post

Comment: I see that you did. You haven't made it any bit clearer what "doesn't work" means. I wasn't talking about grammar.

Comment: @AndrasDeak updated to it to make it clearer.

Comment: So you should call `get_xlist()` on an instance that has that data rather than on a fresh one. When do you set `xxList` for your instance returned by `SerialFirat(self)`? What does that class constructor do?

Comment: well the class constructor is taking the parent but that is really redundant and doesnt do anything at the moment. i was using it to directly write to a list from the parent - which works - instead of writing to a list inside my SerialClass and referencing it in parent. The problem is, since its live data, there is not a time that i can reference to the list when "it's finished". The data just keeps coming

Comment: Well, as you noticed, numpy arrays are mutable but have fixed size, so that indeed won't work (if I understand you correctly). I'd try writing the class `__init__` in a way that if it gets another class instance as additional parameter, it copies the relevant attribute over. That's probably not the proper approach here, but I guess it could work.